# String being returned when fetching a varbinary value

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to read a `byte[]` (`varbinary`) value from a column in a SQL Server table. When I fetch the `byte[]` value from the column using an API, it returns a `varchar` instead of the value stored in the column.

How to fetch the exact data using the API? I am trying to decrypt, using the binary value stored in the column.

I have updated the type to byte in the API code to return the `Byte[]` value but it returns a `varchar`,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBinaryValue([FromRoute] int id)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var Binary Value = await _context.GetBinaryValue.FindAsync(id);

        if (GetBinaryValue == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(GetBinaryValue);
 }

 public partial class GetBinaryValue
 {
    public int Uniquekey{ get; set; }
    public string Value{ get; set; }
    public DateTime SysStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime SysEnd { get; set; }
    public byte [] BinarValue{ get; set; }
}
```

Value in DB: `0x9D8E1A40CA08A569417699547667XXXX`

Fetching the value via API: `nY4aQMoIpWlBdplUdmeQXXXX`

Expected result: `0x9D8E1A40CA08A569417699547667XXXX`

Comment: Its not an SQL Server issue - its your ORM - are you using EntityFramework.

Comment: Yes. I am using Entity Framework.